# My apps won't display "KitKat" toast messages

Tags: android

So I just updated my phone to KitKat android 4.4.2 and the apps I made do not show the new themed KitKat toast. I import `android.widget.Toast` but still not showing the newly themed one. Is my ROM overriding it? However, Facebook does show the new toast. Not really important, just puzzled me.

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This toast is not kit kat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post the code for that Toast

Comment: edited question with code

Comment: What `AppTheme` are you using in `styles.xml`

Comment: `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">`

Comment: What device are you using? And what ROM?

Comment: SGH-M919 Samsung Galaxy S4 T-Mobile Variant. My own custom ROM built from I9505 Official 4.4.2 release. Facebook and other apps show the new KitKat toast but mine don't. I thought it was a system wide theme change where the second a `makeToast` was called it would automatically load the resources from the ROM.

Comment: if you don't use an aosp based rom, or a manufacturer/carrier using those code, while building the rom, you won't get the new toast.. ofcourse you can use a custom toast!

Comment: The code is there, because Facebook and other apps are using the new toast message. I guess I'll wait till my carriers official kit kat release comes out, if it ever does :)

Comment: it could be that Facebook is using their own custom `Toast` view, rather than the KitKat default - it just looks the same? All is working fine with my code that looks the same as that, and Nexus 5 & 7 show it as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, after much confusion. I finally figured it out! :D

I decided to go to the Google source code for the toast notifications. I then decompiled my ROMs framework-res.apk and found the same source. However, i found an aditional source with a "tw" in front of it. This stands for "TouchWiz".

So simply, Samsung was overriding certain toast messages. I simply went and made both sources match the default source and now all my toasts are the nice neat KitKat toast themed :)

Thanks everyone for chatting with me about it!

Comment: So you fixed this locally for your own phone by modding framework-res.apk?   Did you find a permanent solution for the public?

Comment: @David
It seems that it is a context based theme that gets applied. Since I am rooted and have used xposed and inside my xposed modules, I grab the system context and notice that its themed. 

However, when I use the Activity context, it is standard AOSP themed. 

When using a Service or BootReceiver/Receiver context, it is Samsung themed.

There really is not "fix" permanently other than creating your own view and setting that for the toast.

Answer (score 2):

Better use `YourActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Solved my problem... Can you explain why?